# How to build a NestJs api from a mono repository

Tags: angular, docker, nestjs, monorepo, nrwl

I am working on a project where we are storing our code in a monorepo that is "managed" by nrwl. The repo contains a couple angular apps and a couple nestjs apis.

Now we want to dockerize the apis to be able to deploy them to our kubernetes.

I can start a single api by calling `ng serve api1`. I can also build a single api by running `ng build api1`. The problem I've got is that every api needs the full node_modules folder deployed with it. As far as i know angular uses webpack to pack all its depedencies.

Is there a way how to build the NestJs api and include all required node_modules?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the api needing the full node_modules. The build step would take the code it needs from the libs in node_modules and create a bundle that can be deployed. Is this not the case with your setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have actually just released a native way to create monorepos with NestJS, you can read more about the [full announcement here](https://trilon.io/blog/announcing-nestjs-monorepos-and-new-commands) on the Trilon blog

With a standalone NestJS application, you can now simply create (another application, or library) and automatically have it turned into a monorepo workspace.

```sh
# make sure you have the latest @nestjs/cli
npm i --g @nestjs/cli

# if you want to create an app
nest g app my-other-app

# library
nest g lib my-library
```

Now you will be able to use `nest build NAME` to build whichever application you need, and all node_modules etc will be bundled correctly, etc!

---

This new workspace setup will create a naming convention you're used to:

```
# ** FROM

 /src/ ... application code ...

# ** TO

/apps/
  /nest-app/
  /another-app/

/libs/
  /some-shared-lib/
  / ... /
```

The way monorepos are setup in Nest currently is ideal for monorepos that are only nest/node codebases. Frontend monorepos could be held separately somewhere else, as there is limited code (only some interfaces without decorators) that could be shared between FE<>BE.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: i am already on the next project, but i hope it helps others.

Comment: If you want run your service with Docker, you still need to copy completely the `node_modules` inside, or copy the `package.json` and install dependencies inside.
Is there a way to avoid this @Mark?